# Stored Procedure to remove duplicates but keep some data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I am working on SP to help return a list a records to assist with invoicing for certain types of membership...

(I have cut the SP down to work with just one company until I get it going - there will be multiple MembershipType - this example we are using 'Buyer Membership')

So each company will have multiple branches, and each branch will have 3 records relating to the 'invoice line description' which are currently returned on the SP...

### InvoiceLineDescription

```
Branch Monthly Membership
Buyer Monthly Membership
Carrying Charge
```

like so:

```
Company                                         Invoice Line
Id     CompanyName   MembershipType  BranchName Description
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Branch MonthlyMembership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Buyer Monthly Membership
20     Deluxainting  BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Carrying Charge
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch2  Branch MonthlyMembership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch2  Buyer Monthly Membership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch2  Carrying Charge
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch3  Branch MonthlyMembership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch3  Buyer Monthly Membership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch3  Carrying Charge
```

I want to break this down further...

So only returning one instance of
'Buyer Monthly Membership',(for each company)

1 instance of 'Carrying Charge'(for each company)

and then list 'Branch Monthly Membership' for each different branch

So the above data should change to

```
Company                                         Invoice Line
Id     CompanyName   MembershipType  BranchName Description
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Buyer Monthly Membership
20     Deluxainting  BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Carrying Charge
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch1  Branch MonthlyMembership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch2  Branch MonthlyMembership
20     DeluxPainting BuyerMemberShip Branch3  Branch MonthlyMembership
```

I just cant seem to get over the line for this final request

(removing Buyer Monthly Membership & Carrying Charge for branch 2 and 3)

Is this even possible?

Any help please?

**UPDATE**
Thank you for helping me with this... I added in what you suggested and it worked for the first part showing DescriptionGroup and BranchGroup but the second select however is flagging with cteFinal - invalid object name.(your @T) Do I need to declare it globally or how can I get it to use the results?

I tried to put it into a temp variable but then just copied the contents of the SP over to a new table and was able to do a simple select statment...but I would like to get it working as you have shown in your exmaple.. please could you suggest how I can fix the below...

```
 BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    with PCTE AS 

    
(
SELECT  Count(*) as Count, Companies.Id as companyid, Branches.id as branchid, c.name as InventoryCenter
FROM            dbo.InventoryItems INNER JOIN
                dbo.inventoryCategories on InventoryItems.inventoryCategoryID = inventoryCategories.id Inner JOIN
                dbo.InventoryCenters c on inventoryCategories.InventoryCenterId = c.Id INNER JOIN
                dbo.Branches ON InventoryItems.BranchId = Branches.Id INNER JOIN
                dbo.Companies ON Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id
        WHERE 
          InventoryItems.Deleted = 'False'AND
          Branches.IsDeleted= 'False' AND
          Companies.IsDeleted = 'False'  AND
          IsShownToMembers = 'True' AND
          Companies.Id = 20 
        group by Companies.Id, Branches.id , c.name 

)
, CompanySummaryCTE AS
(
    select companyid, branchid, [Part Center], [Equipment Center], [Attachment Center], [Powertrain Center], [Salvage Center] 
        from PCTE
    PIVOT (Sum(Count) for InventoryCenter IN ([Part Center], [Equipment Center], [Attachment Center], [Powertrain Center], [Salvage Center] )) as P
)
, cteInvoices AS (
        select t.CompanyId, t.FirstRun, t.NextRun, f.DisplayedAs as Frequency
            , l.Description as InvoiceLineDescription, l.Quantity as InvoiceLineQuantity, l.DiscountAmount as InvoiceLineDiscount
            , l.ServiceId as InvoiceLineServiceId
            from RecurringInvoiceTemplates t
            inner join RecurringInvoiceFrequencies f on t.RecurringInvoiceFrequencyId = f.Id
            inner join RecurringInvoiceLines l on l.RecurringInvoiceTemplateId = t.Id
    )
, cteFinal AS (
    SELECT Companies.Id as CompanyId, Companies.Name AS CompanyName, p.Name as MembershipType,Branches.Name as BranchName, I.InvoiceLineDescription
    FROM   
    CompanySummaryCTE cte
    JOIN Companies ON cte.companyid = companies.Id
    JOIN Branches on Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id
    JOIN CompanyProducts cp on companies.id = cp.companyid
    JOIN Products p on cp.ProductId = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN cteInvoices I on Companies.Id = i.CompanyId
    where 
    Companies.IsDeleted = 0
    and Branches.IsDeleted = 0
    and p.ProductTypeId = 2
) 

 --Original data with magic numbers added based on partition functions
SELECT DISTINCT * , 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BranchName ORDER BY BranchName, InvoiceLineDescription ) DescriptionGroup,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceLineDescription ORDER BY BranchName) BranchGroup
FROM cteFinal
WHERE 1=1
order by CompanyId 

--Insert into 

-- Once you have the magic numbers worked out, just filter out the rows you don't want
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BranchName ORDER BY BranchName, InvoiceLineDescription ) DescriptionGroup,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceLineDescription ORDER BY BranchName) BranchGroup
FROM cteFinal
) F
WHERE F.BranchGroup = 1 OR F.DescriptionGroup = 1
--ORDER BY F.BranchName, F.InvoiceLineDescription
    

END
```

Comment: Instead of posting pictures can you post sample data (my corporate network blocks imgur.com)

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for the reply, Please find Q edited to show data thanks

Comment: So the general pattern for this would be to first use an analytical function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign some magic numbers to the rows based on the row contents. Then after the fact exclude these special numbers. (i.e. something like `WHERE magicnumber = 1`)

Comment: It'll be quicker if you have time, to represent those sample records as insert statements etc. then anyone can jump in and pose a T-SQL solution

Comment: Create 3 CTES (running analytical functions as @Nick.McDermaid suggested)  and then UNION their output together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something like what you area after. Using this approch you boil grouping down into much simpler expressions. This works for your particaular case but you'll likely need to fiddle with it for your real data, including adding an identifier for which "Description" you want to keep for remaining branches. In this logic, it just keeps the last alphabetical one.

```
-- Note that providing data like this in your question speeds up the answer
DECLARE 
@T TABLE (ID INT, CompanyName VARCHAR(100), MembershipType VARCHAR(100), BranchName VARCHAR(100), Description VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch1','Branch MonthlyMembership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch1','Buyer Monthly Membership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch1','Carrying Charge')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch2','Branch MonthlyMembership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch2','Buyer Monthly Membership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch2','Carrying Charge')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch3','Branch MonthlyMembership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch3','Buyer Monthly Membership')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(20,'DeluxPainting','BuyerMemberShip','Branch3','Carrying Charge')

-- A. Original data with magic numbers added based on partition functions
-- THIS IS FOR ILLUSTRATION ONLY. It is not needed for the final answer
SELECT * , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BranchName ORDER BY BranchName, Description ) DescriptionGroup,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Description ORDER BY BranchName) BranchGroup
FROM @T

-- B. Once you have the magic numbers worked out, just filter out the rows you don't want
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BranchName ORDER BY BranchName, Description ) DescriptionGroup,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Description ORDER BY BranchName) BranchGroup
FROM @T
) F
WHERE F.BranchGroup = 1 OR F.DescriptionGroup = 1
ORDER BY F.BranchName, F.Description
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. Please see my updated Q, your first and second select worked for your example but when I tried to include it into my SP the second select was flagging with @T (I have renamed it to cteFinal) - invalid object name. Please could you explain how I can solve this thank you again for your time Nick. I had to remove the @ from the  @T  in the first select and also change ROW_NUMBER to DENSE_RANK in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: The "Original data" select is (A) for illustration only (have updated the answer) - remove it. Once you define your CTE you can only use it in the immediately subsequent select and then it's gone. So if you remove the redundant select (Leaving only (B) ) you should be fine.

Comment: Ahh I see... I did not know that. You have helped me a lot Nick. Thank You